# Catch Firebase 503 error exception not caught my try statement

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using the Firebase Realtime Database listener to listen to changes on a database path.

My program recently crashed because of the following 503 error that seems to be raised by the underlying `requests` library:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 123, in _start_listen
    for sse_event in self._sse:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/_sseclient.py", line 128, in __next__
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/_sseclient.py", line 112, in _connect
    self.resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url: https://database_url...
```

My listener initialization is wrapped in a try statement, so I'm unsure why this wasn't caught, swallowed and retried as I expected it to:

```
def init_listener():
    try:        
        listener = firebase_admin.db.reference(db_path).listen(handle_change)

    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(1)  # Retry in one second.
        init_listener()
```

I'd like to handle future 503 errors, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Additionally, I'm using `except Exception as e` above for demo/debugging purposes, but I'm also not sure if `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` will be specific enough to catch only 500 errors (though I don't know what other errors can be raised).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [firebase_admin reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#firebase_admin.db.Reference.listen):

> This API is based on the event streaming support available in the
>   Firebase REST API. Each call to listen() starts a new HTTP connection
>   and a background thread. This is an experimental feature.

The key here is that this all runs in a background thread. Therefore, wrapping the call to `listen()` in a `try/except` will not catch exceptions thrown in the thread. There is no simple way to catch the exceptions happening in the background thread.

To solve your issue, you will probably need to know more about why the database is returning an HTTP 503 status. Or you will need to switch to some other `firebase_admin` API that will allow you to catch and ignore these exceptions.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I plan to migrate to Firestore in hopes that it doesn't have the same reliability issues.